# How can I pull every entry (large number) in a section?

Tags: entries, limit

I have an extended profile that users can purchase. When purchased, an entry is created, and tied back to the user.

The user can then log in and access the entry with the extended profile fields.

I would like to have a page that pulls every extended profile entry. This could be in the hundreds. I know Craft will limit the number it returns by default. I also know that I can pass `null` into the limit. `limit(null)`

That seems pretty risky and expensive to run. Is there a better solution? I only need the page title of each entry, so I don't need the entire entry model.

Is this a place to use elementAPI and make ajax call(s) to get all of the entries so I'm only returning the page titles?

Thank you for any suggestions!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use the [`{% paginate %}`](https://craftcms.com/docs/templating/paginate) tag with ajax to limit the number of entries that are pulled at a time.

Comment: I was going to head down the `{% paginate %}` route. For anyone following along, [here is the SO thread](http://craftcms.stackexchange.com/questions/2842/infinite-scrolling-with-craft) I am going to use as a guide. Thank you!