# Inifinite scroll

Tags: pagination

I'm not good in programming and I stuck on making infinite scroll on my website.

Right now I have the code for pagination that looks like this:

```
    {% set query = craft.entries()
    .section('articles')
    .type('naujienos')
    .limit(15)
     %}

{% paginate query as pageInfo, pageEntries %}

{% for entry in pageEntries %}
   {% include 'blocks/_article-with-text.three'  %}
{% endfor %}

</div>

{% if pageInfo.prevUrl %}<a href="{{ pageInfo.prevUrl }}">Previous Page</a>{% endif %}
{% if pageInfo.nextUrl %}<a href="{{ pageInfo.nextUrl }}">Next Page</a>{% endif %}
```

It's very much the same as in Craft CMS documentation and I checked all the topics that are in here but couldn't make it work for me. Maybe someone can help me out please?

Answer (score 1):

To produce an "infinite scroll" like behavior, you'll need to go further than just pagination with TWIG. You'll need to implement some JavaScript. Metafizzy's [Infinite Scroll](https://github.com/metafizzy/infinite-scroll) might be appropriate.

This question has answers that could help you: [Infinite scrolling with Craft?](https://craftcms.stackexchange.com/questions/2842/infinite-scrolling-with-craft/6621)